# How can i use FileSystemWatcher to watch for file size changes?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

A method that set the watcher:

```
private void WatchDirectory()
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = userVideosDirectory;
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Filter = "*.mp4";
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
```

And the event that tell if there is any changes:

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        dirchanged = true;
    }
```

Now i'm checking if there is a new file in the directory.
But now i also want to watch and check if this new last created file size changing. And when the size of the file is not changing anymore give a message like "The file is ready".

How can i watch for the file size in real time untill there is no more changes ?

Comment: Define in 'real time' ?

And you can not watch until there is no more changes, unless you define a rule for it. (For example: 4 seconds no more changes).

Comment: That would only work if you know the expected file size.

Comment: If you want to detect changes to the file size you will need to store the initial file size before you start the `FileSystemWatcher`.  As indicated by @MarkJansen though, you will need to decide how you decide that a file will receive no more changes.

Comment: Oh, and you will have to modify your `NotifyFilter` obviously.

Comment: The file is already written and it's size is 0kb and this is the start. When i set the flag to true that's mean a new file is written already and it's size is 0kb. Now i want to watch the file size progress. If it stay 0kb for let's say 5 seconds then delete the file. But if the file size change after 3-5 seconds then wait another few seconds and watch the file size see if it was changed from the last time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a common problem when using the file system to communicate between two applications. In my experience it works best if you also have a marker file indicating that the "real" file was written completely:

```
SystemA: Writes file theRealFile.txt
SystemA: Writes file theRealFile.rdy (0byte)
SystemB: Watches for .rdy files and then reads theRealFile.txt
```